# Django cache Bad Request (400)

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I currently have my seetings file configures to use the memcache cache.

```
'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache'
```

Whilst the site runs flawlessly, I see debug lines such as:

```
[05/Dec/2014 15:28:53] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('get')
[05/Dec/2014 15:28:53] "get :1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..439e23553bea98b3b35e7b94c1f72576.en-gb.AUS_Eastern_Standard_Time" 400 -
[05/Dec/2014 15:28:53] "GET /RSA/ HTTP/1.1" 200 968
```

So I'm interested in learning how to fix this, and how I can actually test whether the backend cache is being used. It is currently implemented to be used with all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went back to the docks and started playing around with the port number for the location.

Was able to make it report a different error that referenced `63894` as being the correct port number. Interesting to note that it was not the port the actual site was running off - `88`. Maybe it was something to do with the fact that it was running with the `django manage.py runserver` command and was only a development server etc.

Anyway this fixed the problem. Code below as a reference.

```
CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:63894',
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Adapted from previous response*

The only possible reason I see in bad request error is due to misconfiguration of hosts settings as also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875789/django-gives-bad-request-400-when-debug-false).

Also to check for memcached, Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631903/how-do-you-know-if-memcached-is-doing-anything).

Comment: So I already have ALLOWED_HOSTS set up. However, attempting to import the cache form within the shell gave:

`>>> from django.core.cache import cache cache.set('key', 'value')  
  File "<console>", line 1
    from django.core.cache import cache cache.set('key', 'value')
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`