# Django1.8 and Mongoclient settings.DATABASES is improperly configured.

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

i am making an application using django 1.8 and mongoengine 
But when i am trying to configure Django setting.py file to use a Dummy Database , I receive the following error

```
(orahienv) somya@somya-Inspiron-15-3555:/var/www/html/admin_python$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 06, 2017 - 16:57:25
Django version 1.8, using settings 'admin_python.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 06, 2017 - 17:00:15
Django version 1.8, using settings 'admin_python.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<WSGIRequest: GET '/auth/login/?next=/'>
Internal Server Error: /auth/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 164, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 158, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 135, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 235, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/admin_app/context_processors.py", line 30, in init_menu
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 226, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 359, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 10, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 174, in get_user
    user = backend.get_user(user_id)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/admin_app/backend.py", line 29, in get_user
    return TblAdmin.objects.get(pk=user_id)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 328, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 367, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 48, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 39, in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 216, in get_select
    ret.append((col, self.compile(col, select_format=True), alias))
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 346, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 611, in as_sql
    return "%s.%s" % (qn(self.alias), qn(self.target.column)), []
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 337, in quote_name_unless_alias
    r = self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 21, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
[06/Jul/2017 17:00:21]"GET /auth/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 206077
```

I know people asked similar question before. But it's all about the engine value. does any one know how do I solve this error with the NAME value?

setting.py -

```
import os
import admin_app
from django.utils import timezone
import mongoengine
"""from mongoengine import connect
connect('pom')"""

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'uj8$6(ol=!w)b3-luqzb=#6(j19gkbrnp2asq6=xt%5*s2ylz('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = 'mod_spatialite'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'admin_app',
    'celery', #http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'djangoflash.middleware.FlashMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.cache.CacheMiddleware', #http://stackoverflow.com/a/658583/2546013
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'admin_python.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'admin_app.context_processors.init_menu',
                'admin_app.context_processors.server_urls',
                'djangoflash.context_processors.flash',
            ],
        },
    },
]


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
HOST_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8001/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'admin_python.wsgi.application'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8001/'
WEBAPP_URL = 'http://localhost/webapp_angular/'
USERAPI_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/'
HOST_URL_NEW='http://localhost:8001/media/'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
"""
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'admin_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}"""

"""DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 
    }
}
"""
"""
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
        'NAME': 'pom',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
from mongoengine import connect
connect('pom', username='root', password='root')"""
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
    },
}


_MONGODB_USER = 'root'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = 'root'
_MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'pom'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
    'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
    % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # other settings...

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
}
LOGIN_URL = '/auth/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (  
    'admin_app.backend.AuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'admin_app.TblAdmin'

EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'AKIAJB6VACOVZANVTC5A'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Atu9qbV+X5aiwIlQzVAOVjU/AxkxMDV3X0l0FLWweSn9'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'support@doctorinsta.com'

#LOGGING SETTING 
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'applogfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'drinsta.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
            },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
            'handlers': ['applogfile',],
        },
        'drinsta': {
            'handlers': ['applogfile',],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}

#https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine
#https://github.com/dlrust/python-memcached-stats
#We can use the following command to see the keys:
#    python -m memcached_stats 127.0.0.1 11211
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT' : 300 #Default
    }
}
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'

SESSION_ENGINE= 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'

'''
RabbitMQ configurations begins
'''
#OLD FORMAT:
# BROKER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
# BROKER_PORT = 5672   # default RabbitMQ listening port
# BROKER_USER = "admin"
# BROKER_PASSWORD = "admin"
# BROKER_VHOST = "admin" #Virtual hosts provide a way to segregate applications using the same RabbitMQ instance. Different users can have different access privileges to different vhost and queues and exchanges can be created so they only exists in one vhost. 

#NEW FORMAT:
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672/admin'
'''
RabbitMQ configurations ends
'''
'''
Celery configurations begins
'''
#CELERY_BACKEND = "amqp"  # telling Celery to report the results back to RabbitMQ
#'amqp' means Advanced Message Queuing Protocol
# CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = ""
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/Kolkata"
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.cache:CacheBackend'    
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True #If set to True, result messages will be persistent. This means the messages will not be lost after a broker restart. The default is for the results to be transient.
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = None #Never delete the SUCCESSFUL tasks from the database. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-task-result-expires
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'cache+memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'
# CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'memory'
#http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2012/01/27/processing-long-running-django-tasks-using-celery-rabbitmq-supervisord-monit/
'''
Celery configurations ends
'''
```

Answer (score 2):

```
connect(
    db='test',
    username='user',
    password='12345',
    host='mongodb://admin:qwerty@localhost/production'
)
```

and change the `DATABASES` to `DATABASES = {}` section in the `settings.py`

Comment: i edit my code , but still getting same error                             DATABASES = {}

from mongoengine import connect
connect(
db='pom',
username='root',
password='root',
host='localhost'
)

Comment: host need to be given like what i have given, the user/localhost

Comment: i am still getting same error                                                               connect(
db='pom',
username='admin',
password='root',
host='mongodb://admin:root@localhost/pom'
)

Comment: Remove the pom after localhost. / Should be removed too

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to configure a database because you are using mongoengine instead, then remove `DATABASES` from your settings entirely, or change it to an empty dictionary.

```
DATABASES = {}
```

If you do include any items in your `DATABASES` dictionary, then they must include the [`ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ENGINE), otherwise you'll get the ImproperlyConfigured error.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        ...
    },
}
```

Comment: i am getting same error by empty dictionary DATABASES = {}. and problem with second option is that i have mongodb as database is it valid to use sqllite3 engine ?

Comment: I think it is related to engine as given in error. Actually i am replacing sql with mongodb database in this project so first of all i tried to make connection between django and mongodb database but its is giving me this error

Comment: I'm [not sure mongoengine supports Django very well](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine), so I can't help with that. All I can say is that your `ENGINE': '',` in your original question is definitely invalid.

Comment: i am using django1.8 which django_mongoengine  does not support it only support old version of django as i searched i came to know this so i decided to use mongoengine instead. yeah that true ENGINE = '';  is invalid . so that i want to know is any other way to connect ?

Comment: I can't help with recommendations for using mongodb with Django. Note that [Django support was removed from mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/django.html#django-support).

Comment: ohkk still thnx :)